# How to select rows that meet a count condition

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I only want to display companies and locations that have more than 10 locations.

```
select distinct company_id,
count(distinct location_id) location_id_count
from bigtable
where condition1 = 'x'
group by company_id
having count(distinct location_id) > 10;
```

This returns the `company_id` and a count of locations when the company has more than 10 location but what I want to do is see all of the location ids.  Is there a way to do this without a subquery?  There are a lot of conditions in my query and it doesn't seem like a best practice to repeat the same 10 conditions in the where clause in both the main and sub-query.

This is my attempt at a solution, but it is not working well because I am getting about 0.005% extra locations when using a subquery vs. summing the `location_id_counts` from the main query:

```
with MainQry as(
select distinct company_id,
count(distinct location_id) location_id_count
from bigtable
where condition1 = 'x'
group by company_id
having count(distinct location_id) > 10
)

select distinct m.company_id,
b.location_id
from MainQry m
join BigTable b
on m.company_id = b.company_id
where b.condition1 = 'x';
```

Comment: Pleas show sample data and expected output